# Linking object method to html element listener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an object method to an EventListener on an HTML element. But when I do that the `this` variable becomes the elements itself instead of the object.

```
class Foo {
  constructor(element, data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.input = element;
    this.input.oninput = this.update;
  }

  update() {
    this.data; // The context has changed to the element
  }
}
```

Here's my workaround:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(element, data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.input = element;
    this.input.Foo = this;
    this.input.oninput = this.update;
  }

  update() {
    this.Foo.data;
  }
}
```

However, I feel like this isn't the most elegant way of formatting this. How do I program it in such a way that the object's method remembers the object it was apart of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) may help - 
it takes an argument and uses it as its `this` value.

```
var foo = new Foo();
var boundUpdate = foo.update.bind(foo);
boundUpdate();
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed.